# Receber Dados JSON - PHP

Tags: php, json

boa tarde.
Tentei dar uma pesquisada aqui, mas não achei o que preciso.
Estou trabalhando com JSON, e recebi a seguinte string de retorno:

```js
{
    "success": 1,
    "return": {
        "100025362": {
            "pair": "BRL",
            "type": "sell",
            "amount": 21.615,
            "rate": 0.258,
            "timestamp_created": 1418654530,
            "status": 0
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Este número `100025362`, é uma ordem em aberto que possuo.

Porém no momento da consulta desse JSON, eu não tenho o número da ordem.

Eu precisaria correr todas as ordens, para chegar ao status.

Se eu tivesse o número da ordem, não teria problema, ficaria:

```php
$json_ActiveOrder = json_decode($stringJSON);
$ActiveOrderStatus = $json_ActiveOrder->return->100025362->status;
```

Mas como não tenho acesso ao número neste momento, como faria para correr todas as ordens? No caso `100025362`??

Tentei receber somente até `return`, e fazer loop, mas tenho os seguintes erros com o código abaixo:

```php
$json_ActiveOrder = json_decode($retorno_ActiveOrder);
$ActiveOrder = $json_ActiveOrder->return;

foreach($ActiveOrder as $f) {
    echo $f[0];
}
```

O erro sai:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$return in C:\wamp\www\bitcoin\index.php on line 132
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  149328  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0

( ! ) Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\bitcoin\index.php on line 134
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  149328  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
```

Comment: você gostaria apenas de pegar o numero "100025362" ?

Comment: Isso, gostaria apenas de pegar este número!!

Comment: ja tentou `$x = json_decode($stringJSON, true); ` e depois `$x['return'][0]` ?

Answer (score 1):

Pode pegar a chave do array no foreach:

```
foreach($ActiveOrder as $key => $f) {
    echo $key;
}
```

O primeiro erro que aparece é que não existe a propriedade `return` e o segundo pois o `$ActiveOrder` não é um array

Comment: Então, mas como demonstrei, o return tem na lista do json sim.
Vou fazer o teste agora, mas imprimiria no caso $key msm? ou $f?

Comment: Testei aqui, não funcionou :(
Deu os mesmos erros. 
Lembrando que estou setando 

$json_ActiveOrder = json_decode($retorno_ActiveOrder);
$ActiveOrder = $json_ActiveOrder->return;

Comment: da um print da variável $json_ActiveOrder

Answer (score 0):

Faça assim, altere a linha:

```
$json_ActiveOrder = json_decode($retorno_ActiveOrder);
```

para:

```
$json_ActiveOrder = json_decode($retorno_ActiveOrder,true);
```

Isso vai fazer com que a variável $json_ActiveOrder seja uma Array Associativo

Se quiser dar uma olhada na documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php